# Is it wrong to use different type of join in same T-SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

Let's say we have 4 tables:

- T1 (id, f1id, data1)
- T2 (id1, f1id, f3id, data2)
- T3 (id2, f32id, f4id, data3)
- T4 (id2, f3id, f32id, data4)

Usually I am using visual Query builder (SQL Server build in tools) for creating queries.

We need to get all records from T2 but we do not want to see any other data from other table except related from t3 and T1, and NULL if there is no data
I got following statement(from query builder):

```
select 
    t1.id1, t1.f1id, t1.f3id, t1.data2, T1.data1, T4.data3
from 
    t2 
left outer join 
    t1 on t2.f1id = t1.f1id
left outer join 
    t4 on t2.f3id = t4.f3id 
right outer join 
    t3 on t3.f32id = t4.f32id
```

It does produce result I expect, but my boss claims that it is illegal to use right and left join in same statement.

Question: is there a limit or regulation which prevent usage of different type of joins in same T-SQL statements?

Comment: It's not incorrect. But in my personal believe, right outer join tends to make things over complicated when you want to build further onto the query in the future. There are usually ways around it.

Comment: Fear not, the Query Police will not drop from silent black helicopters and spirit you off. It may be confusing, but it isn't a violation unless your employer has specific coding guidelines in place. Tip: A common mistake is converting an `OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` by referencing a column in a `WHERE` clause without allowing for NULLs. You can find SQL Server 2008 limits [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: #HABO why did not put your comments as an answer?

Comment: Since I didn't cite ISO/IEC 9075 chapter and verse I didn't think it was much more than a comment. FYI: On SO the prefix at sign (`@`) is used to notify another user, not an octothorpe (`#`).

Comment: @HABO sorry,twitter habit :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rule about not mixing join type.   Mixing join types is just fine.

But to me that is just an odd query.  You are getting all the rows in t2 and all the rows in t3?